# Reading from a txt file in Python

Tags: python

I have this data (Remark: don't consider this data a json file consider it a normal txt file). :

```
{"tstp":1383173780727,"ststates":[{"nb":901,"state":"open","freebk":6,"freebs":14},{"nb":903,"state":"open","freebk":2,"freebs":18}]}{"tstp":1383173852184,"ststates":[{"nb":901,"state":"open","freebk":6,"freebs":14}]}
```

I want to take all the values inside the first tstp only and stop when reaching the other tstp.

What I am trying to do is to create a file for each tstp and inside this file, it will have nb, state, freebk, freebs as columns in this file.

expected output:

first tstp file:

```
nb state freebk freebs
901 open    6      14
903 open    2      18
```

second tstp file:

```
nb state freebk freebs
901 open    6      14
```

this output is for the first tstp I want to create a different file for each tstp in my data so for the provided data 2 files will be created ( because we have only 2 tstp in the data)

Remark: don't consider this data a json file consider it a normal txt file.

Comment: If we should not consider the input is json then please craft a [mcve](/help/mcve) with a normal text file

Comment: @Zeitounator The input file as a whole is not a valid JSON file, but it clearly is JSON objects concatenated one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This below approach will help you with all types of data available for "tstp" which may have spaces in between.

**I used regex for properly capturing starting of each JSON to prepare a valid data. (Also works If your data is unorganized in your file.)**

```
import re
import ast

# Reading Content from Text File
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()


# Transforming Data into Json for better value collection
regex = r'{[\s]*"tstp"'
replaced_content = ',{"tstp"'
# replacing starting of every {json} dictionary with ,{json}
data = re.sub(regex, replaced_content, data)
data = "[" + data.strip()[1:] + "]"  # removing First unnecessary comma (,)
data = ast.literal_eval(data)  # converting string to list of Json

# Preparing data for File
headings_data = "nb   state   freebk   freebs"

for count, json in enumerate(data, start=1):
    # Remove this part with row = "" if you dont want tstp value in file.
    row = "File - {0}\n\n".format(json["tstp"])
    row += headings_data
    for item in json["ststates"]:
        row += "\n{0}   {1}     {2}        {3}".format(
            item["nb"], item["state"], item["freebk"], item["freebs"])

    # Preparing different file for each tstp
    filename = "file-{0}.txt".format(count)
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(row)
```

Output:

**File 1**

```
File - 1383173780727

nb   state   freebk   freebs
901   open     6        14
903   open     2        18
```

File 2

```
File - 1383173852184

nb   state   freebk   freebs
901   open     6        14
```

- And So on.... for total number of **"tstp" entries**.

**Note:** We cannot **replace "}{"** in every situation. Maybe, in your data the brackets may placed in different lines.

Comment: Use ast.literal_eval instead of eval.

Comment: (also, see `enumerate` instead of managing `count` by hand.)

Comment: Okay, I added **enumerate** and **ast** in code. Thank you @AKX for correction. I forgot the enumerate function.

Comment: @abdeali004 enumerate accepts an optional second argument for `start`, so you don't need `count+1` :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like `}{` is a nice separator for the entries, so let's (ab)use that fact. Better formatting of the output is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
import ast

# (0) could be read with f.read()
data = """{"tstp":1383173780727,"ststates":[{"nb":901,"state":"open","freebk":6,"freebs":14},{"nb":903,"state":"open","freebk":2,"freebs":18}]}{"tstp":1383173852184,"ststates":[{"nb":901,"state":"open","freebk":6,"freebs":14}]}"""

# (1) split data by ´}{`
entries = data.replace("}{", "}\n{").splitlines()
# (2) read each entry (since we were told it's not JSON,
#     don't use JSON but ast.literal_eval, but the effect is the same)
entries = [ast.literal_eval(ent) for ent in entries]
# (3) print out some ststates!
for ent in entries:
    print("nb\tstate\tfreebk\tfreebs")
    for ststate in ent.get("ststates", []):
        print("{nb}\t{state}\t{freebk}\t{freebs}".format_map(ststate))
    print("---")
```

The output is

```
nb  state   freebk  freebs
901 open    6   14
903 open    2   18
---
nb  state   freebk  freebs
901 open    6   14
---
```